# String.replace capabilities

Tags: c++, string

I'm not sure if I fully understand the `string.replace` function

would it be possible to replace a word with **"< array index >"**

So for example given `words[] = { "have", "has", "are", "is", ... }`

"This is a sentence." would end up looking like

"This <3> a sentence."

Or should I use another function?

Comment: Where did the 3 come from?

Comment: It would be the 3rd element in an array in my particular case

Comment: can you please elaborate on <3> more?

Comment: So you are saying you want to specify the number 3, and use a string at index 3 of an array to replace a substring? If the array is called `foo` why can't you just specify `foo[3]` as an argument?

Comment: Not quite, I'm trying to make the sentence smaller. If a word in the sentence is in foo[], I want to replace it with the index.

Comment: Okay, no, that's not going to be doable in a single step. First, you should consider replacing `foo[]` with a data structure with faster lookups, such as a `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`, or a trie. Second, you'll have to look up the index first, then convert it to a string, then call `string::replace`...

Comment: How would you look up the index and convert it?

Comment: Say `foo` is a `std::map` mapping strings to integers, then you would just do `foo[bar]` to look up the string variable `bar` in `foo` (and you get 0 if it's not found). `std::to_string` can be used to convert an integral type to a `std::string` in C++11. In C++03 the idiomatic way is to use a `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in function for this. Programming usually is not about picking one function that does exactly what you want, instead it is all about combining functions.

So what you need is

- A loop over all words in your input
- A search to find the word in your list
- Some code to generate the replacement
- string.replace

Answer (score 0):

`std::string::replace()` is for replacing one string with another - the substitution can be position based, but you can only replace strings with other strings. You cannot embed an int value in the middle of a string using `string::replace()`. See [**std::string::replace**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/):

```
// replacing in a string
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string base="this is a test string.";
  std::string str2="n example";
  std::string str3="sample phrase";
  std::string str4="useful.";

  // replace signatures used in the same order as described above:

  // Using positions:                 0123456789*123456789*12345
  std::string str=base;           // "this is a test string."
  str.replace(9,5,str2);          // "this is an example string." (1)
  str.replace(19,6,str3,7,6);     // "this is an example phrase." (2)
  str.replace(8,10,"just a");     // "this is just a phrase."     (3)
  str.replace(8,6,"a shorty",7);  // "this is a short phrase."    (4)
  str.replace(22,1,3,'!');        // "this is a short phrase!!!"  (5)

  // Using iterators:                                               0123456789*123456789*
  str.replace(str.begin(),str.end()-3,str3);                    // "sample phrase!!!"      (1)
  str.replace(str.begin(),str.begin()+6,"replace");             // "replace phrase!!!"     (3)
  str.replace(str.begin()+8,str.begin()+14,"is coolness",7);    // "replace is cool!!!"    (4)
  str.replace(str.begin()+12,str.end()-4,4,'o');                // "replace is cooool!!!"  (5)
  str.replace(str.begin()+11,str.end(),str4.begin(),str4.end());// "replace is useful."    (6)
  std::cout << str << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

@Brian and @MSalters has given you some good suggestions comments about how to approach your problem, which can be approached in several ways.